# Python/Tkinter autofocus when entry is filled

Tags: python, tkinter, input, widget, compare

I am trying to run a simple script with a simple GUI that compares two strings. As you can see I added two entry fields and a check button that runs my check function. At the start the .focus() is on the first entry widget then I need to input a value select the second entry widget input a value and then press check for the script to compare the two given values.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk



win = tk.Tk()
win.title("Vitek magacin")
win.geometry("200x150")
win.configure(background='gold')

def check():
    c1=no1.get()
    c2=no2.get()

    if c1 == c2:
        print("You win a silly price")
    else:
        print("You win nothing old men")


no1=tk.StringVar()
no2=tk.StringVar()

inputa = ttk.Entry(win, width=12, textvariable=no1)
inputa.grid(column=0, row=1)
inputa.focus()

inputb = ttk.Entry(win, width=12, textvariable=no2)
inputb.grid(column=0, row=2)

ButtonCheck = ttk.Button(win, text='Check', 
command=check)
ButtonCheck.grid(column=0, row=3)

win.mainloop()
```

So what I am trying to make it do is:
When I fill entry one for it to switch focus to entry two and when entry two is filled I want it to run the check function, delete the entry fields, and start over, because these inputs are going come from a bar code reader and I want it to go as automated as possible. Can anyone please help ?

Comment: Simply add `no1.set('')`, `no2.set('')` and `inputa.focus()` at the end of `check()`.

Comment: I don't understand cant you please edit or write an example ? If it's so simple you are a genuis! :D

Comment: How do you fill the entries using barcode reader?  Is there a task to constantly check whether there is data from the barcode reader?

Comment: They computer accepts the bar code reader as an input device, just like keyboard or mouse, there is a button on it you press it when you want to read a bar code .. it shots the laser and you get an input.

Comment: So how do you know that the barcode is read completely if the length of barcode varies?

Comment: It doesn't vary I just want to be able to use it on 6 digit bar codes then 12 digit ones and n digit ones. But the two I compare will always have same amount of digits.

Comment: What I mean is that how the application know that it is a 6-digit bar so that it can advance to next entry after 6 characters are read.

Comment: How is the program supposed to know when you've finished typing in one Entry and it should auto-focus to the next?

Comment: Well that's exactly why I posted here.

Comment: You're going to have to decide the rule for switching focus. Without knowing more details there is no way we can help. Do you want to switch focus after N characters? After you read a newline? After you read a special character from the barcode scanner that says "input finished"? Without some idea of what you expect to trigger the change in focus, we can't really help much.

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this with the bind method.
This is a little wrong and have some disadvantages, but it works if you don't press any additional keys. If you press 'fn' 12 times, for example, there will be a problem, but I think you can solve it.
The idea is that the program counts keystrokes and compares them with the width of the entry field, if the entry field is filled completely, then the program focuses on the second entry field, if the second entry field is also filled completely, then the program performs the function.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title("Vitek magacin")
root.geometry("200x150")
root.configure(background='gold')
s = 0
def check():
    c1=inputa.get()
    c2=inputb.get()
    if c1 == c2:
        print("You win a silly price")
    else:
        print("You win nothing old men")
def checker(event):
    global s
    s += 1
    if s==inputa['width']:
        inputb.focus()
    if s==inputa['width']+inputb['width']:
        check()
inputa = Entry(root, width=12)
inputa.grid(column=0, row=1)
inputa.focus()
inputb = Entry(root, width=12)
inputb.grid(column=0, row=2)
ButtonCheck = Button(root, text='Check', command=check)
ButtonCheck.grid(column=0, row=3)
root.bind('<Key>', checker)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I kinda thought of this too but doesn't this mean that it will only jump focus when I fill 12 characters only ? and it wont work when i try to scan information with lets say 6 characters ?

Comment: Yes, it will jump focus only if you fill 12 characters, but you can fix it by this:
`root.bind('<Enter>', function)` 
It means if you write sth with less than 12 characters and press enter button it will jump focus on next entry or do a 'check' function

Comment: I wont have enter button, only a bar code reader and maybe a touch screen, but this helps a lot, I will most likely use it. Thanks a lot mate.